# Toggle Dropdown not working?

Tags: php, laravel-5, drop-down-menu

I am doing a project in which I show users and when any person click on that user it should has to do a particular task and that is, it has to show a dropdown as written in code
But when I click on the username nothing happens, is just a simple click, **it is not showing the dropdown**

```
 <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
                <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                        <span class="hidden-xs">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <!-- User image -->
                        <li class="user-header">
                            <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                            <p>
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} - Web Developer
                                <small>Member since {{ Auth::user()->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }}</small>
                            </p>
                        </li>    
                        <!-- Menu Footer-->
                        <li class="user-footer">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn btn-default pull-right">
                                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    Logout
                                </a>
                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you might be missing your java script code that performs the toggle function itself. your link has the `class=dropdown-toggle` but nothing to help display the information you want to show.